# How To Get Typescript Compiler To See My Global Types?

Tags: typescript

I have defined some global interfaces as follows in top level of the project:

**globaltypes.ts**

```
declare global {

    my_interface {
        name:string
    }
}
```

But when i try to compile with ts-node, the compiler fails to compile with

"*cannot find name "my_interface" ... diagnostic code "2304"*".

My IDE recongizes the types as global, giving me autocomplete, but how do i get the compiler to do so also such that i can build the project?

**tsconfig:**

```
{
    compilerOptions {
        target: "ES2020"
        module: "commonjs"
        moduleResolution: "node"
        baseUrl: "./"
        allowjs: true
        allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true
        esModuleInterop: true
        forceConsistentCasingInFileNames:true
        strict: true
        typeRoots: ["./"]
        skipLibCheck: true
    }
   "exclude": ["node_modules", "./build/**/*"],
   "include": ["./**/*.ts"]

}
```

If i move the interface declaration into my main.ts file it works fine. I would rather not do this however as i want to access the interface elsewhere also, preferably without importing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need either remove `declare global` and `import` this type or you need to define it in file with **`.d.ts`** extension (see *ambient declarations*).

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules
https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/intro/d.ts